# Querying Gridgain when the cache-value is an array

Tags: gridgain

I have a cache that looks like this:

Key: UUID
Value: Array[Long]

I want to get the key corresponding to a specific value. How does the where-part look like?

I have tried "value = ?" and "_value = ?" but these obviously doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo!

1. What do you mean by Array[Long]? Is it just long[] or may be you are using Scala?
2. The simplest (but not the most effective) way would be using a scan query with predicate [(docs here)](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/SQL%2C+Scan%2C+And+Full+Text+Queries#SQL,Scan,AndFullTextQueries-ScanQueries).
3. To achieve the best performance it is preferable to have your value indexed, so I'd recommend to have a special wrapper class for your array like this:

   ```
   class MyArray implements Comparable<MyArray>, Serializable {
       private long[] arr;

       // implement compareTo,hashCode,equals

       @GridCacheQuerySqlField(index = true)
       public MyArray indexedArray() {
           return this;
       }
   }
   ```

   then the query will look like

   ```
   "indexedArray = ?"
   ```

   where as parameter you have to pass MyArray instance. It is a bit dirty way to index value but this is the only way right now.
4. By the way column names for cache key and value in SQL are _key and _val but not _value and you can write queries like

   ```
   "_val = ? and _key > ?"
   ```

   of course you have to make sure that your key and value at least implement hashCode and equals correctly, implementing Comparable is preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Yes, I am using scala :)